# Make PHP command line display phpinfo page by page?

Tags: windows, unix, php

When I use the PHP CLI to get the phpinfo all I end up with is the last half.  Here is the command:

`> php -i`

I'm not sure what it would be call? But is there a way of controlling the output so that a portion is displayed a piece at a time with the press of a key? Both on Windows and Linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
php -i | more
```

should work on both Linux and Unix. On Linux, though, `more` is simply an alias for the equivalent `less`

Comment: yeah, windows has 'more'. but it's very limited in functionality compared to 'less' (no search, no scrollback beyond what the cmd window offers, etc...).

Comment: just come across the "grep" command that allows you to do regular expression searches.

Comment: I more often use `grep` these days e.g. `php -i | grep mysql` and this would return just the relevant mysql matches

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you could do from the shell

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | less
```

Comment: For command line, php -i is preferable, as phpinfo will wrap the data in html, which isn't particularly readable when it's dumped out en-masse.

Comment: @Marc B nice, I didn't even know about that option. Thanks! Mybe uh... `php -r "phpinfo();"|lynx`...